# difference in the output when we run an html code using notepad++ in Chrome and sending via outlook options

Tags: google-chrome, notepad++, microsoft-outlook-2010

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>stars.css Demos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,100,300,700,400);

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: roboto;
}

body { background: #000; }

.cont {
  width: 93%;
  max-width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4% auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #111;
  color: #EEE;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: thin solid #444;
  overflow: hidden;
}

hr {
  margin: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: thin solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

div.title { font-size: 2em; }

h1 span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #Fd4;
}

div.stars {
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }

label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }

label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
</style>
<link href="http://www.cssscript.com/wp-includes/css/sticky.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>


<div class="cont">
<p><i>Rate Us</i></p>
  <div class="stars">
    <form action="">
      <input class="star star-5" id="star-5-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-5" for="star-5-2"></label>
      <input class="star star-4" id="star-4-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-4" for="star-4-2"></label>
      <input class="star star-3" id="star-3-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-3" for="star-3-2"></label>
      <input class="star star-2" id="star-2-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-2" for="star-2-2"></label>
      <input class="star star-1" id="star-1-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-1" for="star-1-2"></label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run it chrome stars will appear.

When I use the option send via outlook, it displays as

```
()()()()()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### When I use the option send via outlook, it displays as

```
()()()()()
```

This is because Outlook is not a Web Browser.

Outlook only supports a subset of HTML and CSS.

- This hasn't changed since Outlook 2007
- The rendering engine is the same in Outlook 2013.
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx) documents the support for HTML and CSS.
- [The Ultimate Guide to CSS](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) documents what CSS is supported by Outlook. You can see that a lot is missing.

---

> If you’ve been designing and coding emails for a few years now, you’re likely aware of Outlook’s dismal support for email standards. Microsoft switched to Word (from Internet Explorer) as its rendering engine with the introduction of Outlook 2007 and hasn’t looked back (errr, forward?) since. Despite the email community’s efforts and a well-intentioned response from Microsoft, this means that HTML and CSS support in Outlook has remain virtually unchanged between versions 2007, 2010 and now 2013.

Source [Outlook 2013 Still Powered by Word; Now Available for Email Testing](https://litmus.com/blog/outlook-2013-still-powered-by-word-now-available-for-email-testing)